# ¿Como obtener los valores no repetidos en ambos arreglos?

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy comparando dos arreglos en *Angular*, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.
Necesito que el arreglo me devuelva los elementos únicos entre estos por ejemplo;

```js
array1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
array2: [3, 4, 5];
```

Y que me muestre

```js
nuevo_arreglo: [1, 2];
```

Comment: la idea es que los numeros que no se repitan se agregen cono dejar los numeros unicos y eliminar las parejas. si hubiese un 6 tambien entraria en el nuevo_arreglo

Comment: valores no repetido, sera que quieres los valores que tienen en comun dado dos arreglos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes lograrlo usando:

- [`array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/includes) para comprobar si un valor esta en un arreglo.
- [`array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/filter) para recuperar solo aquellos números que cumplen la condición (*no esten en el otro arreglo*).
- [`array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/concat) para agregar a un arreglo los valores en otro arreglo.

#### Opción 1: [Diferencia de conjuntos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diferencia_de_conjuntos)

Los valores de un arreglo que no están en el otro arreglo:

```js
let array1 = [1,2,3,4,5],
 array2 = [3,4,5,6];
 
let nuevo_arraglo = array1.filter(n => !array2.includes(n));
console.log(nuevo_arraglo);
```

---

#### Opción 2: [Diferencia simétrica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diferencia_sim%C3%A9trica)

Los valores que no están repetidos en ambos arreglo:

```js
let array1 = [1,2,3,4,5],
 array2 = [3,4,5,6];
 
let nuevo_arraglo = array1.filter(n => !array2.includes(n))
                    .concat(array2.filter(n => !array1.includes(n)));
console.log(nuevo_arraglo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Usa [lodash xor](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#xor). Según su definición:

> Creates an array of unique values that is the symmetric difference of the given arrays.

```sh
npm i --save lodash
npm install --save-dev @types/lodash
```

```js
import * as _ from "lodash";

_.xor([2, 1], [2, 3]);
// => [1, 3]
```